# Creating email script to send from different email addresses based on user answer choices

Tags: javascript, google-sheets

I work for an organization which has a GAFE account. Multiple users within our organization collaborate on projects, and we have run into a problem when writing email scripts.

We use GForms to collect survey data from users (both teachers and students) within our organization. Depending on the answer choice selected in the form, we want emails to be sent from different email accounts.

For example, we have a reading log that asks 3 questions: title of the book, if the user is a student or teacher, and the user's email address. (The last question is optional, to be completed if the user wants an email confirmation of their submission information. As a result, this field is sometimes blank.) If the user is a TEACHER, we want an email to be sent from an ADMINISTRATOR. If the user is a STUDENT, we want an email to be sent from the LIBRARIAN. (Note: I am neither of these individuals.)

What we tried: In the GSheet which contains the responses to the form, I wrote an email script while logged into my account and saved it. I shared that GForm with both the Administrator and Librarian. Both the Administrator and the Librarian log in, copy the script, make their own with customized fields using an IF statement, then set the trigger for only their customized script.

The problems:
(1) The resulting emails come from BOTH the Administrator and the Librarian, no matter if the user is a teacher or student. 
(2) An error report gets sent when the user does not supply an email address (which is optional in the form).

This is the script I made that is copied & pasted into new script files:

```
function emailScript(e) {
var timestamp = e.values[0];  // Column A data in responses spreadsheet
var user = e.values[1];  // Column B data in responses spreadsheet
var email = e.values[2];  // Column C data in responses spreadsheet
var book = e.values[3];  // Column D data in responses spreadsheet
var subject = "Confirmation of Book Log Submission";
var emailBody = "Thank you for submitting " + book + "to the online book log." ;
//if (user == "Student"){ MailApp.sendEmail(email, subject, emailBody)};
//if (user == "Teacher"){ MailApp.sendEmail(email, subject, emailBody)}; 
}
```

The Librarian deletes the "//" at the beginning of the 1st If statement. The Administrator deletes the "//" at the beginning of the 2nd If statement.

What we want is ONE EMAIL sent. Each teacher gets an an email from the Administrator, and each student gets an email from the Librarian.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What is `MailApp`? Do you have a link to the documentation or a name which I can Google?